# Shadowed underlined text with perspective

Tags: html, css

I have the following html structure where I style my titles with an **underline** and a **shadow**.

```css
.title {
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #32c8ff;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-underline-position: under;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="title">MY TITLE
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: IMAGE: Shadowed underlined text]

I tried to apply a perspective effect with the following css

```css
.container {
    -webkit-perspective: 150px;
    perspective: 150px;
}

.content {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(25deg);
    transform: rotateX(25deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="title">MY TITLE
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: IMAGE: Shadowed underlined text with perspective]

As you can see, it works fine on the text but on the underline the shadow is not displayed and the distance from the text (text-underline-position: under;) is ignored.

Is there a way to display the shadow and keep the correct distance of the underline from the text when using the perspective?

Comment: Have you tried viewing it in different browsers? Wouldn't surprise me if it was a bug in the CSS engine.

Comment: [Pretty much only Chrome supports `text-underline-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-position). What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate the underline with the pseudo element `before`:

```css
.title {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #32c8ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.title::before {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px #32c8ff;
}
```

[See the example here](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielbbica/werjkdgr/)

Comment: I just added margin and changed the line-height and it works like charm! See below

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: 
https://jsfiddle.net/zzhn5gh7/

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 0 auto 60px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  -moz-perspective: 600px;
  -o-perspective: 600px;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #32c8ff;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-underline-position: under;
}

#rotate-x .title {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX( 45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX( 45deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX( 45deg);
  transform: rotateX( 45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="rotate-x" class="container">
  <div class="title">MY TITLE
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wazz/1Ls7y33h/)

```css
.title, .subtitle {
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #32c8ff;
    text-align: center;
}
.title {
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px #32c8ff;
}
.container {
    display: table-cell;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg);
    transform: rotateX(25deg);
}
.content {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg);
    transform: rotateX(25deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="title">GREENPEACE</div>
    <div class="subtitle">THE SURFER</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The right solution for me was the following:

```css
.title {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 2.5;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #32c8ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.title::before {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ffffff;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px #32c8ff;
    margin: 11px 0px;
}
.subtitle {
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 0.7;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #32c8ff;
}
```